# React Native: Best approach to run a background task on iOS when the app is closed?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, background-task

I need to send HealthKit data to a server periodically. I'm using React Native and `rn-apple-healthkit`. I tried `react-native-background-task`, but it won't work while the application is closed (not background mode). I read in Apple developer docs that it happens by design.

I found some solutions online such as geolocation services, running a socket and "playing" silent sounds, piggybacking on push notifications but they all seem like workarounds.

Is there a good way to do this in 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using silent notifications is the correct way of achieving this. However it wont work when the phone is locked:

`For security, the HealthKit store is encrypted when the device is locked, and the HealthKit store can only be accessed by an authorized app. As a result, you may not be able to read data from the store when your app is launched in the background; however, apps can still write data to the store, even when the phone is locked.`

Taken from `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/protecting_user_privacy`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How would you recommend sending a silent notification?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently

Comment: Worth mentioning is that Apple may take issue with you uploading HealthData from the background, as it can be seen as malicious.